# How to recover the label 'Deleted' in Gmail

Tags: gmail, account-management, gmail-labels

I have got two Gmail accounts. The first one created four years ago and the second one a few days ago given that the former has been deleted.

In the Gmail labels, I always noticed that there was a folder called 'Deleted' for the messages that I threw away from the inbox. There was another [below] folder called 'Bin' which was another folder for the same function but only when throwing messages away from a mobile device.

Now that I have signed up with this new account, the Deleted label has disappeared and there is no way to recover it. I tried out to create another label with the name 'Deleted' but of course it has got no function / role in Gmail , hence when I get to delete messages, it remains empty whilst the Bin folder gets filled up.

How can I recover this folder? Or, better, how can I create a new label with the function as main bin?

[image: First account]

[image: Second account that I want to change]

The first picture I posted refers to the first 'normal' account which had the default label, that is, 'Deleted'.
The second picture I posted refers to the new account [created a few days ago] wherein I found out that the above label was not there and could not even be enabled through the settings because it does not exist. Strange but true.

Comment: I suspect that you used a third-party email client using IMAP and it created/used the "Deleted" folder/label. ("Deleted Items" sound like Microsoft Outlook.) Since you've not done the same with this new account, there's no new label. This is just a suspicion, though. Then again, Gmail doesn't have a need for two separate "Trash" labels, so I don't know how else it would have gotten there. (Some other third-party tool, perhaps.)

Comment: What is the "display language" set to in Settings > General? Do you only use the web interface to access your Gmail account?

Comment: You also have `Sent Mail` and `Sent Items` in the first account. `Sent Mail` is Gmail's system label for sent messages.

Comment: What other devices (and apps) have you used to collect your gmail? You mention a "mobile device" (presumably you are not using the web interface on this?), although you say this uses the `Bin`.

Comment: On the mobile, I do not use the web interface and it uses the Bin, not the Deleted Items. It ought to be the contrary, I suppose.....

Answer (score 5):

`Deleted items` is not a system label like `Spam` or `Trash` (`Bin` if you are using English-UK), it's a custom label. You could add it manually, by adding or connecting the third-party app that created it for you if there is any that did that.

In regarding of deleted messages being moved to `Deleted items` instead of the `Trash`/ `Bin` label, Gmail web interface by itself, doesn't move deleted messages to a custom label. This could be done by user or connected app action, like deleting messages from a device with Windows Phone (See references 2 and 3).

Some people don't like `Trash` / `Bin` because it is cleaned up automatically, and prefer to use a custom label to be able to "undelete" their deleted messages at any time, so some developers could made a tool or add this behaviour to their apps.

**References**
1 [Using labels - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708?hl=en)
2 [Deleted emails are sent to the "Deleted Items" folder instead of the Trash folder. Why?!](http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-8/243950-deleted-emails-sent-deleted-items-folder-instead-trash-folder-why.html)
3 [Tired of "Deleting" emails only archiving them? Look no further](http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-7/191258-tired-deleting-emails-only-archiving-them-look-no-further.html)

Gmail System Labels (for English - UK)

[image: Gmail System Labels]

Gmail view message for `Trash` / `Bin` (search [in:trash])
[image: in:trash]

**Attribution**
The references 2 and 3 were shared by the author of the question, [Francis](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/94787/francis), through comments to this answer.

Comment: Yes, it is true. I picked over other Gmail accounts that I have got and none but this one has got the 'Deleted items' label. But now I have got a question  ...how is it possibile that a non-default label without even my authorization, is set as the default trash when i delete a message? If the 'Bin' label is the default label, the deleted messages ought to be moved to this one folder as soon as i push the delete button and not in the 'Deleted items' label. So, why everything is on the contrary in this account?

Comment: `Bin` is the system label for deleted messages in en-UK, not `Deleted items`. If you go into Settings > Labels you can see what the "System labels" are on your system.

Comment: @w3d: You are right. I rolled back answer to the first version.

Comment: _"So, why everything is on the contrary in this account?"_ What sort of third-party tool did you use on this account? An external client? Something to help you manage your messages? Did you migrate from somewhere else? There must have been something.

Comment: I do know that the US version was Trash, no problem about that. As far as I can remember, there's no third-party tool ....
In settings>labels , in the section 'New Labels' it is as if I create labels [I didn't, as far as I can remember] which are actually Deleted Items, Personal, Sent Items, Travel [which are enabled] and 'Receipts' and 'Work' [hidden].
There is something new ....next to the labels, on the right, there is a 'Show in IMAP' enabled with a tick mark! So, if there is a tick mark, it means that it is enabled and showed up.

Comment: What I do not really get, is why when I delete messages, the deleted messages are moved automatically to Deleted items. I am sorry but I really do not know how these labels have been created.

Comment: Btw, I have created a Google+ profile and YouTube account thru this account....I think anyway this has got nothing to do with the topic.

Comment: The "show in IMAP" thick marks for each system and custom labels are not _something new_ , they was there for years.

Comment: "in the section 'New Labels'" - Does it actually state "**New** Labels"? Mine only shows the heading "Labels". "Show in IMAP" (most are checked by default) simply means that those labels will show (as folders) if you connect a third party IMAP client.

Comment: @w3d I am sorry, you are right. It shows merely 'Labels'. :) Thanks

Comment: @Rubén The 'show in IMAP' tick marks for custom labels [for the labels I create] is NOT there. I tried out, as I have already said, to create labels and there is not the 'Show in IMAP'! Only the "strange" account [the one with the 'Deleted Items' label] has got in the labels I create a 'Show in IMAP' tick mark! So, it is not there for years...!
If I create custom labels on the other Gmail account and in the new acocunt I have created a few days ago, there is not the column 'Show in IMAP'.

Comment: @w3d The first image refers to the strange account [with the 'Deleted Items' label]   http://i.imgur.com/uxka1FA.png?1           
The second image refers to the normal account 
http://i.imgur.com/tYiHymu.png?1

So, the 'Show in IMAP' for custom labels is NOT there for years ....^^

Comment: @Francis The "Show in IMAP" checkboxes will only be visible if you have enabled "IMAP" for your account. IMAP only needs to be enabled if you want to collect your email with a third party email client using the IMAP protocol. (So, you must have enabled IMAP on your first account.)

Comment: @w3d Okay ....anyway I found out a forum with my issue.
http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-8/243950-deleted-emails-sent-deleted-items-folder-instead-trash-folder-why.html\

Maybe it's because I connected my phone [Lumia 620] to Gmail - the phone is considered a third-party app and that's why its been created auto-created labels such Deleted Items and Sent Items.

WP to Gmail is a 3rd party connection.
If I use Outlook instead, the deleted emails go straight to the bin [trash].
Actually WP stands for Windows Phone, which, actually, is the app of my Lumia

Comment: @w3d Also this one - http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-7/191258-tired-deleting-emails-only-archiving-them-look-no-further.html

"Currently when I delete an email from my WP it creates a folder called Deleted Items and puts the emails in there. It does not send them to the Trash. So in order to delete them I have to go into the Deleted Items folder and select them to delete them to the trash." ...that's my problem.

Comment: @Francis Yes (that is also what AI E suggested in the first comment), but I thought this was happening on the web interface of Gmail (although maybe that was an assumption)? You stated that when you access Gmail on mobile it (correctly) moves those messages to the `Bin`. So, it seems you are using another app after all. (To be honest, when accessing Gmail on a mobile device - Android or iOS - I have found the best experience to use the dedicated Gmail app, which doesn't actually require IMAP afaik.)

Comment: Right now, I deleted on my laptop the Deleted Items label and now everything I delete, is moved automatically to the Bin, as it should be.
But, as for my mobile, the Deleted Items and the Sent items labels are still there. How can I delete them permanently? How can I configure / snc the mobile version with the web version? Thank you.

Comment: I read again [Comment Anywhere](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). It states that a chat room should be used instead of comments for what we are doing here. I just created a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24133/how-to-recover-the-label-deleted-in-gmail).

Comment: ...to continue discussing there, if is necessary.